# trouble inserting a struct into a set C++

Tags: c++, struct, set, nodes

I am working on an A* pathfinding algorithm, but am having trouble with an error I receive when i insert a struct called node into a set. The error reads: "Error   1   error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const node' (or there is no acceptable conversion)" but the error is found in another file 'XSTDDEF' which i haven't looked at. I am unsure of what it means.

```
struct node{
    int f;
    int g;
    int h;
    int x;
    int y;
};

node coords[24] = { -1 };

std::set<node> open;
std::set<node> closed;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    coords[4].g = 0;
    coords[4].h = heuristic(start, end, start.h);
    coords[4].f = start.g + start.h;
    coords[4].x = 4;
    coords[4].y = 0;

    open.insert(coords[4]);
```

Comment: you need `operator <` for `node` as your compiler tells you

Comment: It means your struct doesnt have operator< which set requires.

Comment: The error message states **exactly** what is wrong - you didn't provide `operator<` for your struct `node`.

Answer (score 1):

As you may know if you've familiarized yourself with the documentation of `std::set`, it is an ordered container. Therefore there must be a way to compare the elements of the set so that they can be ordered. From the documentation, we know that the default comparison functor of `std::set` is `std::less<T>`.

Further, as you may know, `std::less<T>` does:

> Unless specialized, invokes operator< on type T.

Since `std::less` isn't specialized for `node`, it uses `operator<`.

The error message tells you that an overload for `operator<` does not exist that would have `const node` (or anything that a `node` could be converted to) as the left operand.

The solution is to define such overload.

Comment: You shouldn't specialize `less` to do anything but use `<` and that operator should compare completely.  If you need to compare some other way create a comparator class and provide it as a non-default to `set`.

Comment: @CrazyEddie not that I know of a reason to do so, what is your argument for specializing `less` being something that ought not be done?

Comment: You should add possible solution to make this answer complete

Answer (score 0):

std::set is an ordered container so it needs operator< to compare and order elements, allowing fast search. If you don't need this you can use list or vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `operator<`or specialize `std::less` for your struct. Another solution could be to use `std::array`:

```
struct node : std::array<5,int> {
    int &f() { return data()[0]; }
    int &g() { return data()[1]; }
    int &h() { return data()[2]; }
    int &x() { return data()[3]; }
    int &y() { return data()[4]; }
};
```

and you will inherit `operator<` from it. Another benefit - you can access underlying data as array, which would simplify serializing etc.